# Pandas Dataframe sum function with various column criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, criteria

This function sums rows in the dataframe based on 5 different criteria (startdate, enddate, fund, account and analysis):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
    ['02-09-2019',20190902,  20.00,  'F1','B1','I2'],
    ['23-09-2019',20190923,  237.36, 'F1','B1','I1'],
    ['15-11-2019',20191115,  200.00, 'F1','B1','I1'],
    ['16-11-2019',20191116,  2045.00, 'F1','B1','I2'],
    ['05-05-2020',20200505,  205.00, 'F2','B2','I1'],
    ],
    columns= ['Datestr','Datenum','Cost','Fund','Account','Analysis'])


def per_sum(startdate, enddate, fund, account, analysis):
    return df[(df.Datenum > startdate) &
              (df.Datenum < enddate) &
              (df.Fund == fund) &
              (df.Account == account) &
              (df.Analysis == analysis)
              ].Cost.sum()


per_sum(20190000,20200000,'F1','B1','I1')
```

How could I adapt this function, to continue to total cost, if fund, account or analysis data isn't given.

For example:
If I wanted to find the total Analysis 'I2' (in all funds and accounts).

This sort of thing isn't working:

```
per_sum(20190000,20200000,'','','I2')
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Idea is chain by  `|` for `bitwise OR` new constion for compare by whitespace:

```
def per_sum(startdate, enddate, fund, account, analysis):
    return df[(df.Datenum > startdate) &
              (df.Datenum < enddate) &
              ((df.Fund == fund) | (fund == '')) &
              ((df.Account == account) | (account == '')) &
              ((df.Analysis == analysis) | (analysis == ''))
              ].Cost.sum()

print(per_sum(20190000,20200000,'','',''))
2502.36

print(per_sum(20190000,20200000,'','','I2'))
2065.0
```

EDIT:

If want also filter with datetimes one possible solution is add `if-else` statement for chnage start and end datetimes:

```
def per_sum(startdate, enddate, fund, account, analysis):
    startdate = -np.inf if startdate == '' else startdate
    enddate = np.inf if enddate == '' else enddate
    return df[(df.Datenum > startdate) &
              (df.Datenum < enddate) &
              ((df.Fund == fund) | (fund == '')) &
              ((df.Account == account) | (account == '')) &
              ((df.Analysis == analysis) | (analysis == ''))
              ].Cost.sum()

print(per_sum('','','','',''))
2707.36
```

Comment: @RuslanS. - Sure, it was different passed values.

Comment: Thanks :) This doesn't seem to work when I add further criteria. Such as when adding extra account sums from another df called BT:
                BT[(BT.Datenum > startdate) | (account == '') & 
                   (BT.Datenum < enddate )  | (account == '') &
                   ((BT.AccTo == account)   | (account == ''))
                  ].Cost.sum()
               )

Answer (score 1):

This may be not very elegant, but transparent and foolproof:

```
def per_sum_2(startdate, enddate, fund = None, account=None, analysis=None):

    df2 = df[(df.Datenum > startdate) &
              (df.Datenum < enddate) ]
    if not fund is None:
        df2 = df2[df2.Fund == fund]
    if not account is None:
        df2 = df2[df2.Account == account]
    if not analysis is None:
        df2 = df2[df2.Analysis == analysis]

    return df2.Cost.sum()

per_sum_2(20190000,20200000,analysis='I2')

2065.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
per_sum(20190000,20200000,'','','I2')
```

doesn't work because ' ' is not a wildcard fitting all cases/values for that column. You could use regex expressions to match all the values for the column values.

You could change the function declaration to contain default values for the columns, so when you want to ignore one, you do#t give it a parameter when calling the function.

```
def per_sum(startdate, enddate, fund='somepattern', account='otherpattern', analysis):
```